# Command line "open DIRNAME" fails (but "open FILENAME" is OK)

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, bash, folders

In a terminal (or xterm, or emacs) window, the command:
  open *dirname*
(where *dirname* is **.** or **/tmp** or **/home/fred**) doesn't open the the specified directory in Finder.  However:

- Opening a non-directory file works fine, for all sorts of file types.
- "open *dirname*" used to work.  Alas I can't identify what had changed, but AFAIR there was no OS upgrade or bash upgrade.
- It doesn't work as root or as normal user.

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Model Identifier:   iMac8,1
System Version: OS X 10.11.6 (15G22010)
Kernel Version: Darwin 15.6.0

Comment: From the `man open` page,*"open '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/'" opens that directory in the
     Finder.* Just to rule out, can you check man page of your system? Also, is the path being given as a string, just for convincing?

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/open .` just to make sure you're running the system `open`.

Comment: "open '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/'"  doesn't do anything either.

"/usr/bin/open ." is the same -- does nothing.

On Linux I'd use "strace open ." to see what the program is doing, but I don't know OSX so well so I don't know how to trace.

I wonder is there some deep permissions thing that isn't allowing Finder to open a folder?

Comment: On my macOS 10.14.5 Darwin-18.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit, GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1) `open '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/` opens a finder window with the Applications folder.   `open /tmp` also gets opened in a finder window despite being in a hidden directory . (ping me by @ankii).

Comment: Did you already reboot? Can you create a new user account on your Mac and try from there?

Comment: @nohillside -- good idea, silly of me not to try another a/c.  And, **it works properly** on (at least one) other a/c.  So why doesn't it work on *my* a/c?  Grrrrrrr :-)

Comment: Can you try rebuilding the Launch Service database by running `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -v -apps u,s,l` in the user account which is affected?

Comment: Ran the /System/Library/... command.

It gives thousands (literally) of error lines like:

lsregister: error -10811 registering /System/Library/CoreServices

lsregister: error -10811 registering /System/Library/CoreServices/.disk_label

lsregister: error -10811 registering /System/Library/CoreServices/.disk_label.contentDetails

lsregister: error -10811 registering /System/Library/CoreServices/.disk_label_2x

Still producing messages after 4 minutes. Will report when complete whether "open ." works

Comment: lsregister gave 68241error lines as above.
Sadly, "open dirname" still doesn't work (but "open -R still DOES work).

Answer (score 1):

from `man open`:

> ```
>  -R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.
> ```

So try `open -R '/home/fred'`

(Technically you don't need the single-quotes around `/home/fred` unless there are spaces or special characters, but it doesn't hurt to use them anyway.)

Comment: `open -R /tmp` opens root directory(not `tmp`) in finder, while `open /tmp` opens tmp directory despite being in a private directory. See my comment above too.

Comment: Partial success!  **open -R** *dirname* does work -- it correctly opens the parent directory.

(However, as mentioned before, **open /tmp/** does nothing.)

Also, invoking as **open -a /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app** makes no difference: it works with **-R** and doesn't work without.

Comment: For directories it should work without `-R`. It works in my case on Mojave.

Comment: `-R` is primarily for files with an associated application. `open novel.doc` will open in Word, `open -R novel.doc` will reveal it in Finder. As it always opens then enclosing folder that way, `open -R /home/fred` will open `/home` to show the `fred` folder.

Comment: Sure, -R isn't perfect, but it's much better than not working at all.  E.g. open /a/b gives me Finder open in /a with /a/b selected, so pressing Enter gets me there without using a mouse. A useful workaround -- thanks!